# IIS Website (.net / mvc / entity framework) published to live server is throwing 'network path not found error'

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have published a mvc/entity framework website to a windows cloud server with sql eval edition installed, I am now receiving the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The network path was not found

My config is:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=False;User Id=user;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Full error below:

```
    [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1418
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +470
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +945
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +114
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1637
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +132
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +246
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +567
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +238
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +916
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +117
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +212
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +135
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +175
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +293
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +187
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +483
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +274
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes() +63
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext() +31
   CMT.DAL.UnitOfWork..ctor() +86
   CMT.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String client) +118
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +186
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +399
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

The process hosting the web app cannot connect to or logon to the SQL Server.

There are multiple possible reasons for this, but no further detail is available. It could be

- Outbound firewall (on web server) blocking connection
- No network route (or intermediate router/firewall blocking access)
- Inbound firewall (on web server) blocking connection
- SQL Server not set to accept TCP/IP connections
- SQL Server TCP/IP configured to use a different port
- Invalid login details

Or maybe something else network/access related.

Comment: Thank you, let me look into those and report back

Comment: My tech company advised that there was an issue with the ip address, e.g. it was connected to the WAN not the LAN, ive marked this answer as correct as bascially this led me to connect with my tech company

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEK5f.png)

Ensure TCP/IP for your server is enabled.

Notice that your mentioned Entity framework, have you tried the following structure for your connection string?

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="DatabaseContext"  
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/BloggingModel.csdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.ssdl| 
                                                       res://*/BloggingModel.msl; 
                                           provider=System.Data.SqlClient 
                                           provider connection string= 
                                               &quot;data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
                                               initial catalog=DBNAME; 
                                               userid=user;Password=Password 
                                               multipleactiveresultsets=True;&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The *BloggingModel* changed it to your model name.

More details can be found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thank you, TCP/IP is enabled and still doesnt work (it was already enabled)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my reply with another possibility. Take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't think that EF migrations work with model first EF (look at the stack trace). Code first EF uses a "normal" connection string.